# How to work in a function on a variable from outside a function - based on it's name as a string

Tags: python, scope

How convert string to a Python object?

I have for example simple function:

```
def test_function(name):
   str(name) + "insert(1, "test_01")
   ...

test_function("list1")
```

I want this to perform "list1.insert(1, "test_01) operation but it doesn't work. I guees there is a problem that it reads name as a string not as an object. How can I solve this out?

Comment: you can use `eval` to evaluate an expression represented as a string. However this is rarely the right approach to solving a problem

Comment: You are passing a string as a parameter so the function will receive a string. If you want to pass a list to the function you need to pass in a list.

Answer (score 0):

locals()"YourFunction"

or

```
globals()["YourFunction"]()
```

as an example:

```
def foo(number):
    return number*10

print (globals()["foo"](10))
```

Output= `100`

Thanks

Comment: if you are happy with the answer , I will be grateful if you vote .

Answer (score 0):

***NOTE***

*By any means* don't use `eval`, it is insecure ("eval is evil").

For more details about `eval` harmfulness read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!).

***Solution Requested***

Using `eval` you can evaluate string that contains code and execute it.

The code here that is being evaluated, looks for the variable `name` in the global scope (outside the function).

The [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) dictionary contains the variables defined outside the function.

```
def test_function(name):
   eval(f'(globals()["{name}"]).insert(1, "test_01")')

name = "list1"
list1 = []

test_function(name)

# Outside function
# eval(str(name) + '.insert(1, "test_01")')

print(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's what you really want. But i think it's because of the quotation mark. See below:

```
def test_function(name):
   print(str(name) + 'insert(1, "test_01")')
   ...

test_function("list1")
```